# Cant read JSON produced by PHP into my javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Im using AJAX to request a php file that returns JSON

```
$.ajax({ url: 'php/invoice.php',
         dataType: "json",
         data: {id: 1},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
         }
});
```

The php file im using is echoing json via json_encode:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $queryResults[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($queryResults);
```

an example of what the php is sending back is:

> [{"id":"1","firstname":"Brent","lastname":"Doe","telephone":"888888888","zip":"11111"}]

What im getting when I alert(response) is "[object Object]"

What I want is to alert the first name or any other property in the json ie. "Brent"

Iv'e tried alert(response.firstname); and it returns as undefined.

iv'e also tried to remove the dataType: "json" from the ajax request and just parse the json when it gets returned via var obj = $.parseJSON(response) and alert(obj.firstname)

I dont know what im doing wrong, I also dont know why there [ ] around the json when I use json encode. Im assume its because its returning a array from json objects which may be my problem? Im new to this and would appreciate any help or resources!

Iv'e done a couple hours of research and still cant find a answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The response is an **array** so you have to do `response[0].firstname`. Have a look at the question I linked to, it explains how to access (nested) arrays and objects.

Comment: Thanks this solved it! Will take a look at that question, feels like I looked through a lot of questions but must have missed that one! Thx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here (as **@echeese** first pointed out)

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $queryResults[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($queryResults);
```

Notice how the JSON looks (notice the `[..]` ?)

```
[{"id":"1","firstname":"Brent","lastname":"Doe","telephone":"888888888","zip":"11111"}]
```

It translates to this:

```
0 => {"id":"1","firstname":"Brent","lastname":"Doe","telephone":"888888888","zip":"11111"}
```

and you need to access it like this:

```
response[0].firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you're having is that your response is returning an array of objects. You should be able to get the first name by using `response[0].firstname`

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried every combination. But this solved it. Thanks much for the quest response. Will mark as answered as soon as it lets me!